# WP CF7 custom var

Tags: posts

I have a trouble with WP CF7

```
[dynamichidden custom-prod-code "CF7_custom_prod_code"]
```

in my php :

```
add_shortcode('CF7_custom_prod_code', $val->code_prod);
```

html result :

```
<input 
type="hidden" 
name="custom-prod-code" 
value="CF7_PROD_CODE" 
size="40" 
class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7dtx-dynamictext wpcf7-dynamichidden" 
aria-invalid="false"
>
```

the add_shortcode is not on the function.php

regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've read the [shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). A shortcode must be a callback (i.e. a function), not a value. And `add_shortcode` only works for the shortcode *name*, not an attribute:

`dynamichidden` is the *name* of the shortcode, and `CF7_custom_prod_code` is an attribute. You won't be able to hook into it using `add_shortcode( 'CF7_custom_prod_code' )`. You can however use the `do_shortcode_tag` filter to modify the output of *any* shortcode handler:

```
add_filter( 'do_shortcode_tag', function ( $html, $name, $attr ) {
    if ( $name === 'dynamichidden' && in_array( 'CF7_custom_prod_code', $attr ) ) {

        // Do something with $html

    }

    return $html;
}, 10, 3 );
```